# Biber error TexMaker

Tags: bibliographies, biber, texmaker

I tried to compile my file. My main problem was that I couldn't get my bibliography. I use TexMaker on macOS.

Now, I get this message:

```
Process started

INFO - This is Biber 2.14 INFO - Logfile is 'mydocument.blg' INFO - Reading 'mydocument.bcf' INFO - Found 1 citekeys in bib section 0 INFO - Processing section 0 INFO - Globbing data source 'references.bib' INFO - Globbed data source 'references.bib' to references.bib INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'references.bib' for section 0 INFO - LaTeX decoding ... INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'references.bib' ERROR - BibTeX subsystem: /var/folders/q5/yw2xj5zd3n5_59mz7pkbl6bh0000gn/T/biber_tmp_IYx9/references.bib_10335.utf8, line 2, syntax error: found "author", expected "," INFO - ERRORS: 1

Process exited with error(s)
```

I edited Bib(la)tex to point to `"/usr/local/texlive/2020/bin/x86_64-darwin/biber" %.bcf`

My bibliography only contains one entry:

```
@online{ceticwebsiteenquelquesmots
author = {"notme"},
title = {article_title},
year = {notreallynow},
url = {url_of_the_article}
}
```

Could you help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: texmaker is not involved at all here, that is just teh editor you used to write the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are missing a comma after  `ceticwebsiteenquelquesmots`

Comment: Thank you. I thought that I made a typo while editing the file here but I forgot the comma in the original file.

Comment: @Dunno yes that is exactly what the error message that you quoted in the question  says: `found "author", expected ","`